# What's a better way to write this?

Tags: c#, zipcode

```
public string SomeMethod(string  OriginalZip) {

     string zip = "Zip Not Available";
     zip = GetZip(zip, OriginalZip);
     return zip;
 }
 
private static string GetZip(string zip, string OriginalZip)
{

     int zipLength = (OriginalZip.HasValue) ? OriginalZip.Value.ToString().Length : 0;
     int NumOfLeadingZeroes = (zipLength > 0 && zipLength < 5) ? 5 - zipLength : 0;


    if (OriginalZip.HasValue)
     {
         zip = OriginalZip.Value.ToString();
         for (int i = 0; i < NumOfLeadingZeroes; i++)
         {
             zip = "0" + zip;
         }
     }
  
    return zip;
 }
```

Comment: Seems a bit broad of a question. Is there something in particular you have a question about?

Comment: What is `.HasValue` for type `string` (it doesn't compile)? Usually `.HasValue` and `.Value` is for `Nullable<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to state the problem (reverse engineering) and then solve it. As far as I can see,
we want to *pad* `0` from the left for `zip` to have at least `5` digits. If your case then

```
private static string GetZip(string value) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
  ? new string('0', 5)
  : value.PadLeft(5, '0');
```

usage:

```
public string SomeMethod(string originalZip) {
  string zip = GetZip(originalZip);

  ...
}
```